# Process the sound wave just before going to the speaker

Tags: android, audio, processing

Is there any way I can process the sound wave that goes to the input of the speaker before it gets played? I want to change the Decibel values for the different frequencies.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of effects you want to apply. You can use [SoundPool.setRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate%28int,%20float%29)  to simply change the pitch. If you want to get more complicated effects consider using [AudioEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html).

> > I want to change the Decibel values for the different frequencies.

That's exactly what [Equalizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) effect is doing. You can retrieve the band for desired frequency using [Equalizer.getBand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html#getBand%28int%29) and  than change its level with [Equalizer.setBandLevel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html#setBandLevel%28short,%20short%29).

Comment: I need more bands so that the effect is more visible.In the 5 band equalizer the effects cannot be identified that much.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean right before the digital-to-analog conversion, then no, you can't do that from an app. What you can do is to process the audio before writing it to your AudioTrack instance, or by using an AudioEffect as Andrei suggested. In both of these cases the audio might still go through additional filters in the platform's audio DSP (e.g. multiband compression, peak limiting, equalization to compensate for the particular speaker component used, etc) before reaching the DAC.

It sounds to me like you want to modify the audio signal in the frequency domain, so you could take a look at e.g. [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/), which has a C interface as well as a Java wrapper, so you can use it both from native code and Java code depending on what you feel most comfortable with. I've never used it myself so I can't provide any info on how to integrate it into an Android project.